# Unable to map compiled JS file to the source TS file in Electron's browserWindow

Tags: typescript, electron, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug a typescript file that is preloaded in Electron's browserWindow but I'm unable to map the compiled file correctly to the source file.

I'm getting this warning in the console

```
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: file:///C:/Users/aabuhijleh/Desktop/Projects/testing/electron-typescript-quick-start/views/preload.js.map
```

Chromium is apparently looking for the `.map` file relative to the loaded html file?

This is how my project structure looks like

[image: project structure]

[Here's my repository](https://github.com/aabuhijleh/electron-typescript-quick-start)

UPDATE: On macOS, I'm not getting this error but I'm still getting it on Windows

Comment: The console logs of main and preload are different. main process logs will appear on the terminal. preload script logs will appear in the browserWindow Chromium devtools console. This is how Electron works. A "preload" script is literally just a script that is preloaded in the browserWindow. From the Electron documentation, the preload script "Specifies a script that will be loaded before other scripts run in the page."

Comment: You can still debug the preload script in Chromium's devtools. The problem is that you are debugging the compiled JavaScript instead of the Typescript.

Comment: How did you run your project? `npm compile && npm start`?

Comment: "npm start" should be enough. "npm run compile" will run automaticly.

Comment: anyhow I didn't face such issues. When I run the project then it works.

Comment: The project runs fine. The problem I'm describing in my question is the fact that the JavaScript file  is not being mapped correctly to the TypeScript file which makes debugging the code much harder as I have to put breakpoints on complied JavaScript instead of the actual TypeScript file. I want to fix the issue behind this warning `DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: file:///C:/Users/aabuhijleh/Desktop/Projects/testing/electron-typescript-quick-start/views/preload.js.map`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be Electron's problem. When loading the "preload.js" script, it does not consider the path of the script relative to "index.html", but assumes that they are in the same folder.

A workaround is setting "inlineSourceMap": true in tsconfig.json, then the source map and the scripts are in the same file.

UPDATE:

In addition to using tsc, we can also choose Webpack to compile TypeScript for Electron.

see https://blog.scottlogic.com/2017/06/06/typescript-electron-webpack.html