# tsc not emitting correct sourceMapURL location

Tags: typescript, source-maps, tsc

I'm having issues with using `"sourceMaps": true` in my tsconfig.json

I currently have tsc set up so that `src/services/database.ts` generates `dist/services/database.js` and `dist/services/database.js.map`

However the generated `sourceMapURL` is missing the directory (e.g. `database.js.map`), which causes the debugger to attempt to load `dist/database.js.map`

Is there some way to have tsc either have the source map URL reflect the actual location, or put all the map files in the root folder so the URL is correct?

### Additional information

Here's the entire tsconfig.json:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    },
    "target": "ES2020",
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "ignoreDeprecations": "5.0"
  },
  "formatCodeOptions": {
    "indentSize": 2,
    "tabSize": 2
  },
  "include": [ "src/**/*" ],
  "exclude": ["./out", "./dist", "./node_modules"]
}
```

This application is an Electron Windows desktop application, rather than a browser based web application. When loading the application, DevTools displays the following for each source file:

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for file:///C:/Users/me/project/dist/floatingnotification.js.map: Unexpected end of JSON input
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for file:///C:/Users/me/project/dist/pickfilterview.js.map: Unexpected end of JSON input
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for file:///C:/Users/me/project/dist/pickroleview.js.map: Unexpected end of JSON input
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for file:///C:/Users/me/project/dist/sidebar.js.map: Unexpected end of JSON input
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for file:///C:/Users/me/project/dist/searchBar.js.map: Unexpected end of JSON input
etc.
```

Comment: Could you share your `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: The sourceMappingURL path is relative to the file it maps, so it shouldn't have the directory in it

Comment: @GabrielLobo that's interesting. Then this might be a DevTools problem rather than a tsc problem. This is an Electron app rather than a website, so it's an unusual environment. I'll provide more information here when I have a moment.

Comment: Turns out this is an Electron problem rather than a tsc problem. The solution here is working for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61125913/unable-to-map-compiled-js-file-to-the-source-ts-file-in-electrons-browserwindow   . I have marked the question as duplicate